# Anyway to "format" this json file, I can't seem to use run or count to make it work in mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, import, formatting, keyword-search

This is a sample of the json file that I've imported into my mongodb, I want build a basic index on it to search fields for relationship.

```
{  
  "business_id":"93otbGHE0s0m-lU1osvg9w",
  "name":"Rivertowne",
  "neighborhood":"North Side",
  "address":"337 N Shore Dr",
  "city":"Pittsburgh",
  "state":"PA",
  "postal_code":"15212",
  "latitude":40.4459861,
  "longitude":-80.0108802,
  "stars":3.0,
  "review_count":102,
  "is_open":1,
  "attributes":[  
    "Alcohol: full_bar",
    "Ambience: {'romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'classy': False, 'hipster': False, 'divey': False, 'touristy': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'casual': True}",
    "BestNights: {'monday': False, 'tuesday': False, 'friday': True, 'wednesday': False, 'thursday': False, 'sunday': True, 'saturday': True}",
    "BikeParking: True",
    "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards: True",
    "BusinessParking: {'garage': False, 'street': True, 'validated': False, 'lot': False, 'valet': False}",
    "Caters: False",
    "CoatCheck: False",
    "GoodForDancing: False",
    "GoodForKids: True",
    "GoodForMeal: {'dessert': False, 'latenight': False, 'lunch': True, 'dinner': True, 'breakfast': False, 'brunch': False}",
    "HappyHour: True",
    "HasTV: True",
    "Music: {'dj': False, 'background_music': False, 'no_music': False, 'karaoke': False, 'live': False, 'video': False, 'jukebox': False}",
    "NoiseLevel: loud",
    "OutdoorSeating: True",
    "RestaurantsAttire: casual",
    "RestaurantsDelivery: False",
    "RestaurantsGoodForGroups: True",
    "RestaurantsPriceRange2: 2",
    "RestaurantsReservations: False",
    "RestaurantsTableService: True",
    "RestaurantsTakeOut: True",
    "Smoking: no",
    "WheelchairAccessible: True",
    "WiFi: free"
  ],
  "categories":[  
    "American (New)",
    "Pubs",
    "Nightlife",
    "Bars",
    "Restaurants"
  ],
  "hours":null,
  "type":"business"
}
```

But after I imported into json, the count and find all turn up zero. An expert told me the json file was not formatted the right way, so it won't fit my mongdb requirement. I have to find a different version of this json file.

Is there way to fix this?

```
attribute 

GoodForDancing: True

And attribute

RestaurantsAttire: casual

--------------------PART B.----------------- 

GoodForDancing: True

And attribute

RestaurantsAttire: dressy
```

I want to compare some things, out of restaurants with the attribute "Good For Dancing" I want to see how many have casual vs. dressy attire. I want to do a query search for both part using key, but so far count and find showed up 0.

This is my import command, business is the collection name and yep is the dbname:

```
mongoimport --db yelp --collection business --file /home/dachen/Desktop/business.json
```

My find command turned up nothing, so obviously json file is something wrong with it

```
db.business.find({ "attributes.GoodForDancing" : { $exists : true } })
```

People say the syntax is wrong, "", anyway way to fix it?

Comment: Can you please prettify the Json so it is readable?